# Filter result based on sum of child's column

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have following tables.

```
diplomas -> id, name
users -> id, name, email
diploma_user -> id, user_id, diploma_id, invoice_id (many to many relation)
invoices -> id, user_id
invoice_items -> id, invoice_id, item_type, item_id, price
payments -> id, invoice_id, amount
```

Invoice can have multiple payments in different amount.
So I want to get all the users which have pending invoice payments?
How that's possible? I have tried different queries but that's not working at all.

Comment: Where do you store the invoice total?

Comment: @iamab.in I calculate it runtime based on invoice_items price.